# Avoid rotation of one view in viewcontroller with orientation change

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, orientation

I need to avoid rotation of single view inside the `viewcontroller` when orientation change. When user change the orientation of the device viewcontroller should be rotated but one view inside that `viewcontroller` should be kept as itis. Is there a way to achieve this task. I saw many applications use this technique but don't have idea to do this.

Like [Adobe Draw App](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/adobe-illustrator-draw/id911156590#)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my above question and I state it here because it can be useful for someone.

If you need to keep position as itis of particular `view` inside the `viewcontroller` when changing the device orientation we have to rotate that view in inverse direction at the same speed. In iPads rotation duration is `0.4s` and in iPhones it will take `0.3s`

Example code:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    var timeDuration: TimeInterval = 0.4 //for iPads
    if DeviceHardware.deviceIsPhone() {
        timeDuration = 0.3 //for iPhones
    }

    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {

        if UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeLeft{
            UIView.animate(withDuration: timeDuration, animations: {
                let degrees : Double = 0; //the value in degrees
                self.relevantView!.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(degrees * .pi/180))

            })
        }else{
            UIView.animate(withDuration: timeDuration, animations: {
                let degrees : Double = 180; //the value in degrees
                self.relevantView!.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(degrees * .pi/180))

            })
        }

    } else {

        if UIDevice.current.orientation == .portraitUpsideDown{
            UIView.animate(withDuration: timeDuration, animations: {
                let degrees : Double = -90; //the value in degrees
                self.relevantView!.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(degrees * .pi/180))

            })
        }else{
            UIView.animate(withDuration: timeDuration, animations: {
                let degrees : Double = 90; //the value in degrees
                self.relevantView!.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(degrees * .pi/180))

            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did post an updated solution that seems more robust by concataning a inverse transform of the system one. This way you do not have to deal with static duration regarding the device.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to apply an inverted animation rotation to your views to cancel the system rotation:

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

```
coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (context) in
    
    self.nonRotatingView!.transform = self.nonRotatingView!.transform.concatenating(context.targetTransform.inverted())
    
    
}) { (context) in
 
    // Something to do on completion ?
    
}
```

}